# A gambling riddle?

Tags: probability

I hope you're not going to hate me for my bad phrasing of this question, because I'm not a mathematician.
So, the problem goes like this:

We have an unknown number of gamblers, and each of them has different amount of cash - from few bucks to few thousand. 
The goal is to transfer money to one individual(no matter who) - all the money, or a given sum.

Those players, however, cannot exchange money or interact with each-other in any way, but each of them can gamble with the casino.

When gambling with the casino, one has 47.5% chance of doubling a bet and 52.5% of losing the bet.

What is the best and most reliable way to do this and loose as little to the casino as possible?

Edit: A real life example - Imagine there are many players that want to cash out their points but neither one of them has anything near the minimum cash-out amount, so they come together and try to figure out a strategy to gamble until someone has enough points to cash-out and then split the money

Comment: How is this going to transfer money to the given individual?  The given individual is either going to gain money from the casino or lose money to it (more likely the latter) via that individual's bets, not from anyone else's.

Comment: Ok, the word transfer might be a bit out of context but you get the idea, one must hold all or a given amount of cash at the end

Comment: This is not clear.  You could have each person bet all their money.  Then, with probability $\approx .86$ at least one person will double their money.  At that point, all winners could cash in and split the proceeds.  But if only one person  wins, this represents a significant loss.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Worth noting:  Since the bets are so unfair, it is generally wiser to place big bets...as you limit the "fees" that are constantly being extracted in the form of unfair odds.

Comment: This may work better if the players can place opposite bets. For example, gambler 1 bets on red at roulette while gambler 2 places a equal bet on black on the same wheel at the same time. But this does require them to interact in some way to coordinate the bets.

Comment: @lulu do you assume one double is enough to cashout, because it is not in most cases. Imagine we have 1/few players holding the majority of the points and this/those player/s lose, then no matter how many of the low point players win no one will be able to cash out. This is the problem with the all-in solution you propose - it is not reliable.

Comment: @Nigel  I am not assuming anything.  As I said, your question was unclear.  I was asking whether or not the mechanism I mentioned was satisfactory and if not, why not.  Absent coordination (which you appear to forbid) I don't see how to do any better.  Of course, if they can coordinate on bets they can guarantee winners, to a point.

Comment: @DavidK  Of course, in roulette there is the possibility of neither side winning (the ball can come up $0$ or $00$).  I can't think of perfectly offsetting bets that can be made, though maybe I am being unimaginative.  Are there any?

Comment: @lulu Initially I was thinking you accept a small chance of losing everything, but you could have another confederate bet a small amount on 0 and 00 to further hedge the bets. You must expect _some_ loss due to the house edge.